# Report Portal Launch is not stopping

Tags: format, protractor, cucumber, report, reportportal

I have a protractor-cucumber-framework project and am running my test on selenium standalone server. And have set reports in protractor.conf.js file as "**format: ['json:reports/results.json', 'progress',`${reportPortalFormatter}:${tempFile.name}`**]"

However once my test execution finished and i check reports in report portal i see Launch is showing in-progress.

Seen all the configuration and specs are file. Not sure how to deal with it.

Version of frameworks I have Below details might help you:
"cucumber": "4.1.0",
"@reportportal/agent-js-cucumber": "5.0.1"
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "5.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on protractor-cucumber-framework project. For the reports to be generated we used two ways.

1. Generate parallel reports which can be generated using package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'
2. Generate the html report when all your tests are executed. Set the report in onComplete event. It will generate the report once all the tests are executed.

Below is the code which I have used in the project for point2.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of never-ending Report Portal launches from WebdriverIO (which is quite similar to Protractor actually, we've migrated from Protractor) and found [this issue resolution here](https://github.com/BorisOsipov/wdio-reportportal-reporter/issues/134#issuecomment-743321029).
The problem was that [RpService, {}] was misplaced (outside the services:[] or inside another service, can't remember now).

Solved by fixing the config in wdio.conf.js to

```
services: [['selenium-standalone'], [RpService, {}], [another_service]]
```

Also check the reporters config to be

```
reporters: [[reportportal,rpConf], [another_reporter]]
```

Should work for Protractor too.